# Which one is correct: await you going in hell or await you to go in hell?

Tags: gerunds, present-tense, present-participles

Please help me to understand this:

```
I will await you making that folder public.
I will wait for you coming out of your house.
```

Or,

```
I will await you to make that folder public.
I will wait for you to come out of your house.
```

Which one is more right grammatically? Please tell me when should I use something like:

```
something(I want you) + gerund + object
```

For me, something like-

```
I want you doing this work everyday.
```

Although, alternative of that is "I want you to do this work everyday" which is correct. But I just want to know is this correct "I want you doing this work everyday"? Please elaborate the difference as well.

Answer (score 2):

> I want you doing this work everyday.

This phrasing is not correct.

You should say instead:

> I want you **to do** this work everyday.

As to the sentences in the body of your question, neither is correct.

You should say instead:

> I await you to go **to** hell.

But the whole sentence would sound so much better if you just said instead:

> I am waiting for you to go to hell.